# Resolve all already created service instances from .NET service provider

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-5

I would like to request all created instances from a transient service via the IServiceProvdier. My problem is that requesting them seems to create additional instances instead of retrieving only the already existing instances.

I have a service interface and implementation

```
public interface ISomeService {}
public class SomeService : ISomeService 
{
  public SomeService() 
  {
  }
}
```

It is registered transient

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>();
}
```

Another service where I try to get all already created services

```
public class AnotherService 
{

   // calls the constructor of SomeService
   //public AnotherService(IEnumerable<ISomeService> instances) {}

   public AnotherService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
   {
     // calls the constructor of SomeService
     //IEnumerable<ISomeService> instances = serviceProvider.GetServices<ISomeService>();

     // calls the constructor of SomeService
     //IEnumerable<ISomeService> instances = serviceProvider.GetRequiredServices<ISomeService>();
     
   }

}
```

I don't know why the constructor of SomeService is called but it definitly seems to do it due to the calls of Get...

Anyone managed to get the list of instances without creating one?

Comment: yeah, thx, I know the definition and the scopes. Just trying to figure out if there is a way to retreive the instances in case we want to monitor/log how any instances are there (without writing the code for each service)

Answer (score 0):

By definition a transient service will always be created each time you request the service provider or the DI system to resolve it.

If you want to reuse the same instances you can register services with a different lifetime

```
services.AddSingleton<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```

or

```
services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```

if you register the dependency as a singleton than there will be a single instance of there service for the entire application lifetime.

if you register the dependency with the scoped lifetime than a new instance will be created for each scope. In Asp.Net a scope consists of a request.

If you want your dependency to be transient and want to have track of all the instances that have been created you can do a little trick using static references:

```
public static class SomeServiceReferences {
    public static readonly IList<ISomeService> References { get; } = new List<ISomeService>();
}
public class SomeService: ISomeService {
    public SomeService() {
        SsomeServiceReferences.References.Add(this);
    }
}
```

but I don't reccomend this approach cause holding the reference of those dependencies might cause performance problems and if you need to do such a thing there might be some problems with the design of your application.